# Backuppc won't backup due to no ping success

Tags: debian, backup, backuppc

I have a working installation of BackupPC and I try to add a host, that is only reachable through a different host. For this reason, I created a ssh config file and reaching the host via rsync or ssh is no problem.

But now I can't start a Backup because BackupPC tries to ping the host before starting the backup. The strange thing is, that the ping command and the NmbLookup command for that host are set to `/bin/echo`. I have also tried to use `/bin/true` but this did also not succeed.

So I don't know what I could try next.

Thanks for any Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is solved. I tried it the different way round:

- I added a ClientNameAlias with the value 127.0.0.1 so that the ping succeeds
- Then i tried to override the client rsync options to the name in the ssh config

Now backuppc connects to the remote host and the ping command succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem by manually editing the /etc/hosts file on the BackupPC server.
Nothing made sense. I could ping the host from the BackupPC server just fine and other backups using identical settings were working perfectly. I first tried using the PC's IP address instead of the hostname. That got past the ping and seemed to work but there were were other problems: (tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME)